# POST method is not working on Flask application - Error 404

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a simple Flask application that will run a web app that connects to a Postgres database.

However, when I run the code and click the submit button, the POST method does not work, so it does return the {{url_for('success]}} as specified. I have tried adding and removing several components.
I have methods=['GET', 'POST'] already.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from sqlalchemy.sql import func

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/Jeopardy'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__="allc"
    number = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String())
    question = db.Column(db.String())
    answer = db.Column(db.String())


    def __init__(self,number,category,question,answer):
        self.number = number
        self.category = category
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/success", methods=['POST','GET'])
def success():
    if request.method=='POST':
        category=request.form['category']
        question=request.form['question']
        answer=request.form['answer']
        number=request.form['number']
    
        print(email, height)
        if db.session.query(Data).filter(Data.number == number).count()== 0:
            data=Data(number,category,question,answer)
            db.session.add(data)
            db.session.commit()
            
            return render_template("success.html")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug=True
    app.run()
```

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<title>Jeopardy</title>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="../static/style.css" rel="stylesheet"  >
</head>
<body>
    <div class="="container">
        <img src="../static/logo.png" alt="Jeopardy" class ="logo">
        <!-- @todo - message-->
        <form action = "s{{url_for('success')}}" methods="POST">
            <div class =  " form-group">
            <h3>Jeopardy Question</h3>
            <input
                    type = "number"
                    name = "Index"
                    placeholder= "Type number" />
                <input
                    type = "text"
                    name = "Question"
                    placeholder= "Type the Jeopardy question here" />
                    <input
                        type = "text"
                        name = "Answer"
                        placeholder= "Type the Jeopardy Answer here"/>
                <button type = "submit"> Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

While running the code my app renders successfully, but when submitting a number the server does not register the input. When loading the success page separately, it loads.
In the terminal, I see: `"POST /success HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your html

It should be `method="post"` and not `methods="post"`

EDIT:

Another typo in

```
action = "s{{url_for('success')}}"
```

Remove the "s"

Comment: When running in terminal, I still get the same error. : `"POST /s/success HTTP/1.1" 404 - '

Comment: you have another typo... action = "s{{url_for('success')}}". There is an extra "s"

Comment: 404 means that the page was not found... the error should have change after changing the method

Answer (score 1):

here is typo:

```
<form action = "s{{url_for('success')}}" methods="POST">
```

change it to:

```
<form action = "{{url_for('success')}}" method="POST">
```